# Attaching listeners to body doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, mouseevent

I can't figure out why this piece of code isn't working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body onload="
document.body.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
alert(123);
},false);
"></body></html>
```

There isn't even any error whatsoever.. it just does nothing.

amazingly if I change `'mousedown'` to `'keydown'` it works

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html><head></head><body onload="
    document.body.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    alert(123);
    },false);
    "></body></html>
```

(I'm using Chrome btw)

Comment: Hm, why would you want to attach an event in an `onload` inline event handler...

Comment: @bazmegakapa . the file is saved as `test.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of *this* in listeners attached to the body element behaves a little differently in different browsers. Try the following in Firefox and an older version of IE (note that it's specifically for this case, it isn't meant to be a general "what is this?" function):

```
<head>
<title>Some "this" tests</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

var whatIs = (function(global) {
  return function(that) {

    // If String(that) isn't useful, try some stuff
    if (String(that) == '[object]') {
      if (that == global || that == window) {
        alert('window');
      } else if (typeof that.tagName == 'string') {
        alert(that.tagName);
      } else {
        alert(that);
      }

    // Otherwise show that
    } else {
      alert(that);
    }
  }
})(this);

</script>
</head>
<body onclick="whatIs(this);"  onload="whatIs(this);">
  <div onmousedown="whatIs(this)">this</div>
</body>
```

In all browsers, the onload shows *window* and clicking on the div show *this* as the div. Clicking on the body shows *this* to be *window* in Firefox but the *body* element in IE, Opera and Chrome.

Comment: nice find. so is firefox wrong or is firefox right and every1 else wrong?

Answer (score 4):

[It works fine](http://jsbin.com/opequ4/3) ([see the code](http://jsbin.com/opequ4/3/edit)).

Notice that I added some content and added a border to `body` so that you can see its dimensions. [If you remove the content](http://jsbin.com/opequ4/4), everything you see is a black line. `body` does not take up any space if there is no content (like any other block element) which implies you cannot click inside of it.

It seems you thought that `body` would spread across the whole browser window, but that is not the case.

If you attach the handler to `window` instead, it gets all events that happen inside the visible area.

Comment: if you are saying `body` doesn't spread across the whole browser window.. how do you explain why does `<body style='background-color:red;'>` make the entire screen red?

Comment: @Pacerier: Good question... the answer could lie here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/body. `body` has a decprecated `bgcolor` attribute which sets the background color of the document. I assume that that the CSS `background-color` is applied the same way (for backwards compatibility?) See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.bgColor

Comment: @Pacerier: If you use Chrome anyway, click somewhere in the window, select `Inspect Element` from the context menu and select the `body` element in the DOM tree. You will see the highlight in the page and it does not cover the whole view.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use jQuery bind. It does not only make you code less but is also supported by most browsers. Try this one:

```
$('body').bind('click mousedown', function() {
  alert(123);
});
```

Comment: I think you have that backwards - browsers don't support a bind method for DOM elements, jQuery has a bind method for its jQuery objects. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the global window object instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body onload="
window.addEventListener('click',function(e){
alert(123);
},false);
"></body></html>
```

For the given HTML, the body has no height and width, so it will not receive any mouse events when you click on the window.  It still can receive key events though.  If you give it a height and width, it will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body style="height:1000px; width:1000px" onload="
document.body.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
alert(123);
},false);
"></body></html>
```

Comment: btw why is the theory for that document.body doesn't work if its a mousedown but works if its a keydown?