# why doesn't the onload event binds the `this` variable as expected?

Tags: javascript, web-services, web-applications

does anyone knows why doesn't the onload event binds the `this` variable as expected?

Like in this test script, onkeydown gives us true (`this` is working fine) but onload gives us false (`this` now points to window.. wth?):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<script>
function f(t){
alert(t===document.body);
}
</script>
</head><body onkeydown="f(this);" onload="f(this);">

</body></html>
```

Comment: it _is_ actually an event of the window AFAIK. Just speculating, maybe there was just no other clear way to be able to put it in html as an attribute, so it ended up on the `body` tag...

Comment: try just alert(t).  My gut feeling is that it might be `window`

Comment: @natedavisolds.. i do know that it is a window, but not why it is a window.

Comment: Wasn't your question answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246430/attaching-listeners-to-body-doesnt-work)?

Comment: @RobG i actually asked this question before that got answered.. didn't expect them to be related though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLBodyElement):

> **HTMLBodyElement.onload**
>
> Exposes the [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) event handler to call when the window gains focus.
>
> Note that this handler is triggered when the event reaches the window, not the body element. Use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) to attach an event listener to the body element.

The important part is *this handler is triggered when the event reaches the window*. The handler is executed in the context of the `window` and not the `body`.

FWIW, `alert(window.onload === document.body.onload);` will yield `true`.

Comment: Note that the reference is the **Mozilla** documentation, not the W3C. Please also see what the [HTML5 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers-on-elements-document-objects-and-window-objects) says.